# Check Java Driver version in clients from Db2 server

Tags: db2, java, jdbc

I have a Db2 database that is being used by many applications in different servers. I want to check from the Db2 server if the Java driver used in the different client applications is up-to-date.

Is the any way to check the version of the java driver client from the Db2 server?
I have tried the following without success:

```
db2 list application show detail
db2 "SELECT *  FROM TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(cast(NULL as bigint), -2)) AS t"
```

In the last command, the `CLIENT_PRDID` column could have some of this information, but it only shows: `JCC04110` and I do not know what does it mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0001170.html  describes the client_product_id monitor element thus

> Use this element to identify the product and code version of the data server client. It is in the form PPPVVRRM, where:
>
> PPP identifies the product. This is "SQL" for IBM® relational database products.
>      VV identifies a 2-digit version number.
>      RR identifies a 2-digit release number.
>      M identifies a 1-character modification level (0-9 or A-Z).

comparing what CLIENT_PRDID shows

`SELECT distinct CLIENT_PRDID  FROM TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(NULL, -2))`

`JCC04220`

vs the jdbc type 4 driver version

`java -cp $DB2_HOME/java/db2jcc4.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version`

`IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.22.29`

gets a close match for me.  I can't say I know why the mod level is not set.

on a different system, looking at the type 2 driver, I get `JCC03690` from `CLIENT_PRDID` but `IBM DB2 JDBC Universal Driver Architecture 3.72.44` from `java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version`.. so it's maybe nearly of right...

Answer (score 0):

This page lists jcc version by Db2 version http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

I would assume that JCC04110  is a 4.11 version

Comment: That is the problem, your assumption is not true. The Java driver has a three parts number (4.19.26), not just two parts as you said (4.11). This is the evolution of the JDBC drivers in Db2: http://angocadb2.blogspot.com/2014/08/jdbc-driver-version-evolution.htm